# Azure DevOps Ant task reports success (with errors)

Tags: azure-devops, ant, azure-pipelines, javac

Forgive me if this is not the right place to ask. I'm trying to track down an issue I'm having with a client. They have a build.xml that when executed in an Ant task we can force compilation errors in the code, see them reported in red in the task logs, but the task reports success.

Self-Hosted Agent, Java 1.6, Ant 1.7.1, Windows Server 2016.

```
<target name="asdf" depends="asdf">
<mkdir dir="asdf" />
<mkdir dir="zxcv" />
<copy todir="sdfg">
...
</copy
<javac includeantruntie="false"
 destdir="asdf"
 failonerror="true"
 debug="on">
 <src path="src" />
 <classpath refid="zxcv" />
</javac>
...
</target>
```

And the output log contains:

```
[javac] Compiling...
##[error] ... <===== red
...
[javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
...
##[section]Finishing: task name <===== green
```

I've tried adding failonerror="true" in what I think are appropriate places with no luck. I suspect the issue is somewhere in the build.xml and will continue researching that path, but thought I would ask here in case it were a setting or something I missed in the Azure Pipelines Ant task.

It has also been suggested to upgrade the version of Ant, and will be passing along that recommendation to the client as well, and will update progress if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the ant version issue. I can reproduce above issue with Ant 1.7.1.
[image]

When i upgraded Ant to version 1.10.5, it worked as expected, the Ant task failed if the build failed.
[image]

You can try upgrading the Ant in Self-Hosted Agent machine to a newer version.

Comment: Thank you Levi Lu-MSFT, I'm having the upgrade the Ant version now. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Confirmed. Added Ant 1.10.8 to the server, updated ANT_HOME and PATH, restarted Agent and now seeing the Task fail as expected!

Answer (score 0):

@ovation22 - If you're using a YAML build pipeline you can look for continueOnError attribute configured for the job or step. Since you are stating that the Ant step shows green yet has a ##error call in it, this is likely the case. If you aren't using a YAML pipeline (I.E. Classic/GUI pipeline) I believe there is a checkbox for this in one of the drop down sections of either the job or the individual step/task. I would recommend you look here as this is likely the cause of your issue.

See here for reference: [YAML Schema - Step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#steps)

Comment: Hi Source Code. I should have mentioned, yes classic pipeline and I did double check that "Continue on error" in the task was not selected. I appreciate the reply.